# WP: How create a Live Tile like the one used by "Photos" app

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I want to create a Live Tile that contains a moving image, like the Live Tile of "Photos" app.

[image: Image: first position]

[image: Image: second position]

How can I do that? Does exist any library to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Cycle Tile template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207036%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

> The Cycle Tile template cycles through between one and nine images.